# Rename objects in for loop in R

Tags: r

Some brief guidance if possible while learning R:

Created `for` loop drawing a set of histograms:

```
for ( i in 1:10) {
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=data[,i], fill=Group)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=200, alpha=.5, position="dodge")
  print(p)
  p[i] <- p
}
```

I would like to assign different names to `p` to call these plots separately later on. I would have thought adding `p[i] <- p` would have been sufficient. 
What is the mistake I am making? Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use `assign`

```
for ( i in 1:10) {
                 assign(paste0("plot", i),  ggplot(data, aes(x=data[,i], fill=Group)) +
                                                   geom_histogram(binwidth=200, alpha=.5, position="dodge") )
                 }
```

This will create each plot as a different object (`plot1`, `plot2`, `plot3` ... ) in your global environment

Answer (score 4):

your first assignment to p from ggplot reset p each time and your `p[i] <-p` cannot work as it is the same object on both sides of the assignment. You want to use:

```
pList <- list()
for ( i in 1:10) {
   p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=data[,i], fill=Group)) + 
   geom_histogram(binwidth=200, alpha=.5, position="dodge")
   print(p)
   pList[[i]] <- p
}
```

Then you can access the different plots as `p[[1]]` etc.

Comment: Thanks cmbarbu! Worked perfectly.